# How to control display speed in manim?

Tags: manim

I found in manim there are two kinds of way to display animation, one way is to use`self.play()`and by adding `run_time = X`in `kwargs`, the speed of animation can be set and the animation will finish in X seconds.

But I found another way to display by first adding an object with updater using `self.add()` and wait it to display using `self.wait()`.

How to control the speed if use `self.add()` and `self.wait()`?

[There is a demo to show the case](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/examples.html#rotationupdater)

BTW, I'm using manimgl instead of community version in order to achieve real time rendering.